# Uma solução para quebrar/continuar um loop em Python?

Tags: python, loop

A questão é a seguinte, eu não consigo encontrar uma solução que substitua o uso do console para minha pequena aplicação.

O que acontece é: Meu aplicativo roda em loop eterno, porem após ele executar o loop, ele deve parar para peguntar se eu desejo parar o loop ou continuar. Até ai nada impossível. Porem, eu quero que ele continue o loop se eu não fizer nada. Por exemplo:

1. Abro o programa.
2. O programa executa o primeiro loop.
3. Aparece uma mensagem: "Aperte qualquer tecla para parar ou aguarde 4 segundos."

A partir desse momento existe duas possibilidades.

1. Aperto qualquer tecla e o programa fecha.
2. Eu não aperto nada e o programa continua.

Eu já pensei em algumas coisas, como por exemplo utilizar duas threads uma para ler as teclas(se houver) e outra para contar os 4 segundos, porem eu não consegui. Então eu venho perguntar se alguém conhece uma solução para este problema.

```
import pyautogui
import sys, time, msvcrt, random, time, os

# obs: Minha resolução de tela é 1366 x 768. Talvez será necessário adaptar as coordenadas
#      dos cliques automatizados para sua tela. 

def jogar():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.click(670, 330)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    cartaEscolhida = random.randint(1,5) # Escolhe uma carta aleatória.
    if cartaEscolhida == 1: 
        pyautogui.click(670, 330)
    elif cartaEscolhida == 2:
        pyautogui.click(717, 350)
    elif cartaEscolhida == 3:
        pyautogui.click(771, 351)
    elif cartaEscolhida == 4:
        pyautogui.click(815, 357)
    else:
        pyautogui.click(863, 350) 
    time.sleep(7.5)
    pyautogui.click(760, 410)

def abrirJogo():                # Dá os cliques para abrir a extensão e o jogo de cartas.
    pyautogui.click(891, 537)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(694, 386)

def fecharJogo():               # Dá os cliques para fechar a extensão.
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.click(880, 531)

def mudarAba():                 # Para mudar da aba do console para a aba do navegador.
    pyautogui.keyDown('alt',)
    pyautogui.press('tab')
    pyautogui.keyUp('alt')

def pararPrograma():
    timeout = 4
    startTime = time.time()
    inp = None
    print("Aperte qualquer tecla para continuar ou aguarde 4 segundos.")
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            inp = msvcrt.getch()
            break
        elif time.time() - startTime > timeout:
            break
    if inp:
        sys.exit()
    else: 
       parar = False

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')  # Para limpar o console. 

# Daqui pra frente é o programa funcionando. 

print("Abra o canal na twitch e deixe em modo teatro. O programa iniciará em 10 segundos.")
time.sleep(10)
parar = False
while parar == False:
     abrirJogo()
     jogar()
     fecharJogo()
     mudarAba()
     clear()
     pararPrograma()     
     mudarAba()
```

Também coloquei o código fonte no site [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/mUgGfCzU) e gravei um [vídeo executando ele](https://streamable.com/sn4n3).

Obs.: O código fonte atual funciona, porem eu quero resolver esse problema pois desejo utilizar uma interface gráfica.

Para simplificar um pouco mais o problema eu fiz isso:

```
from threading import Thread
import time, sys

def pergunta():
    print("Aperte qualquer tecla para parar ou aguarde 4 segundos.")
    input()

def contar():
    timeout = 4
    startTime = time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - startTime > timeout:
            print("Continuando")
            break

ThreadA = Thread(target=pergunta)
ThreadB = Thread(target=contar)

ThreadA.start()
ThreadB.start()
```

Agora o problema muda. O input não encerra após terminar os 4 segundos. E eu não posso chamar essas threads de novo.

Comment: Bom, basicamente tu vai usar o comando Break, e talvez o Continue/Pass ou Timer...

Comment: Sim. Eu usei o time para contar de 1-4(pararPrograma). E o break também. Porem eu não consigo fazer essa contagem/ler uma tecla. E se uma tecla for pressionada antes da contagem terminar, o programa parar.

Answer (score 2):

Bom galera. São 4:31 da matina e eu resolvi. =D Vou postar no Google drive já que são códigos quase idênticos.

A solução foi eu colocar a thread(exclui uma) dentro de um while com um for. Dessa forma toda vez que a thread terminar ela vai voltar pro while que vai repetir a thread.

E o input eu deixei como algo normal. Porem agora, Assim que passar 4 segundos e nada for pressionado, o programa digitará "continuar" e continuará o loop.

obs: O v3 é onde está a solução.

[The link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1om5hwLWWOC4Jy0wGamYrAWW9Dph5npic)

Comment: seria legal colocar pelo menos a parte do código relevante aqui, links podem deixar de existir, ou outros usuários podem até não ter acesso